# How to store indeces of a row if the row element exist in another list?

Tags: python, indexing, compare

I am reading a row in file in which each word is a long code but I need only 9 or 10 first letters( it could be of 9 or 10 letters) to compare with another list of codes.
Moreover I have to store indices of row each time the code exist in the two list.

```
list_to_compare=open(file,'rb').readlines()
with open('file', 'rb') as f:
       L=[]
       Index=[]
       F=[]
       for line in f:
              L=line.split('\t')

              for ind in range(len(L)):
                  code=L[ind][:9]
                  code2=L[ind][:10]
                  if code and code2 in list_to_compare:
                      Index.append(ind)
                      F.append(code) and F.append(code2) #
```

I don't uderstand why is not working

Note: The list to compare is a file in which each code is '\n' separated.

The row I'm working on is huge.

Comment: Why is it not working? What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: How do you want to compare `code` and `code2` with `list_to_compare`?

Comment: I expect index as a list of index of row in which I find the words that are also in list_to _compare . But I have an empty list

Comment: list_to_compare is a file that I previously opened

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `and` is wrong. `and` is an boolean operator.
Since `F.append` returns `None` the second append is never executed.
With more readable variable names, I get this:

```
with open('file', 'rb') as lines:
    indices = []
    codes = []
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.split('\t')
        for ind, part in enumerate(parts):
            code = part[:9]
            code2 = part[:10]
            if code in list_to_compare and code2 in list_to_compare:
                indices.append(ind)
                codes.append(code)
                codes.append(code2)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Since I still obtain an empty list, is it possible that i don't read correctly the list_to_compare?

Comment: It doesn't work, beacuse the 10th character is '-' in code, so code2 includes code too by adding '-'. Do I introduce an if statement?

Comment: Not clear to me, what the condition for `code` and `code2` is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483089/how-to-find-substring-and-store-indexes-of-the-list-in-case-it-found/37483810?noredirect=1#comment62465741_37483810